# Connection error, timeout when I am web-scraping with Python on debian

Tags: python, browser, web-scraping, debian, try-catch

I have got a web-scraping script, which is working on thousands links.
But sometimes i get connection error, timeout error, bad gateway error and my script is just stop..

Here my part of code (in the urls i have got links which ones i run with a loop):

```
def scrape(urls):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    datatable=[]
    for url in urls:
        browser.get(url)
        html = browser.page_source
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })
```

I think i have to use a try-catch methode to avoid it, and if it is happening try again to read this website.

My question is where and what i have to build into my code, to catch these errors and try again/go to the next link?

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url, params={'s': thing})
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
    # what i have to write plus and where i have to place correctly this part?
```

Thank you!

Comment: sometimes server had timeout limit of 30sec which means your script will be killed if it does not complete within the timelimit. If that is the reason, you can use this scraping on the background task using celery.

Comment: I never used celery, and plus i am totally beginner in Linux+in python, so probably if i cant solve it with try-except method, i just reopen the script with a job scheduling (crom)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I've dealt with these sorts of errors previously, I've written a decorator that will retry the function call a certain number of times if a given exception is raised.

```
from functools import wraps
import time
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from socket import timeout

class Retry(object):
    """Decorator that retries a function call a number of times, optionally
    with particular exceptions triggering a retry, whereas unlisted exceptions
    are raised.
    :param pause: Number of seconds to pause before retrying
    :param retreat: Factor by which to extend pause time each retry
    :param max_pause: Maximum time to pause before retry. Overrides pause times
                      calculated by retreat.
    :param cleanup: Function to run if all retries fail. Takes the same
                    arguments as the decorated function.
    """
    def __init__(self, times, exceptions=(IndexError), pause=1, retreat=1,
                 max_pause=None, cleanup=None):
        """Initiliase all input params"""
        self.times = times
        self.exceptions = exceptions
        self.pause = pause
        self.retreat = retreat
        self.max_pause = max_pause or (pause * retreat ** times)
        self.cleanup = cleanup

    def __call__(self, f):
        """
        A decorator function to retry a function (ie API call, web query) a
        number of times, with optional exceptions under which to retry.

        Returns results of a cleanup function if all retries fail.
        :return: decorator function.
        """
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
            for i in range(self.times):
                # Exponential backoff if required and limit to a max pause time
                pause = min(self.pause * self.retreat ** i, self.max_pause)
                try:
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                except self.exceptions:
                    if self.pause is not None:
                        time.sleep(pause)
                    else:
                        pass
            if self.cleanup is not None:
                return self.cleanup(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_f
```

You can make a function to deal with a failed call (after max retries):

```
def failed_call(*args, **kwargs):
    """Deal with a failed call within various web service calls.
    Will print to a log file with details of failed call.
    """
    print("Failed call: " + str(args) + str(kwargs))
    # Don't have to raise this here if you don't want to.
    # Would be used if you want to do some other try/except error catching.
    raise RequestException
```

Make a class instance to decorate your function calls:

```
#Class instance to use as a retry decorator
retry = Retry(times=5, pause=1, retreat=2, cleanup=failed_call,
              exceptions=(RequestException, timeout))
```

With `retreat=2`, the first retry will happen after 1 second, the second retry after 2 seconds, the third after 4 seconds etc.

And define your function to scrape a website, decorated with your retry decorator:

```
@retry
def scrape_a_site(url, params):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    return r
```

Note that you can easily set which exceptions will trigger a retry. I've used `RequestException` and `timeout` here. Adapt to your situation.

With regards to your code, you could adapt it to something like this (having defined your decorator with the first block of code above):

```
#Class instance to use as a retry decorator
retry = Retry(times=5, pause=1, retreat=2, cleanup=None,
          exceptions=(RequestException, timeout))

@retry
def get_html(browser, url):
    '''Get HTML from url'''
    browser.get(url)
    return browser.page_source

def scrape(urls):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    datatable=[]
    for url in urls:
        html = get_html(browser, url)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })
```

Note that you are applying `@retry` to the smallest block of code you can (just the web lookup logic).

Comment: Woah, its a very complex post, thank you! Can you add it plus how it is showing in my code?

Comment: It's not too bad when you break it down. It's worth understanding decorators at some point, but they are a fairly advanced topic. Useful though. The important thing is that you apply a decorator to a function block which lets you automatically retry that function if a particular set of exceptions are raised. Very useful if you have a number of functions which may all need to be retried - you can just apply the `@retry` decorator to each function definition.

Comment: Thank you, it is running, few hours/days and i can check it and i hope it is working :D

Comment: No worries! The only thing I would suggest is that you pass some sort of function (I've given one example here) to the `cleanup` parameter, so that you have some sort of record of calls that fail after the maximum number of retries. You don't have to re-raise an exception in such a function - just printing out details of failed calls might be enough for you.

Comment: Hm. It stopped with this error code: "raise exception_class(message,screen,stacktrace)selenium.common.exception.TimeoutException:Message:Error loading page, timed out(checkLoad)

Comment: Then you probably need to add that particular exception to the list of exceptions covered by the `retry` decorator. `from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException` in your import statements. And when you instantiate your `Retry` instance, `exceptions=(RequestException, timeout, TimeoutException)`

Comment: Wow!  Worked out of the box for me with scraperapi.